# Making a unknown amount of variables

Tags: python

I'm trying to declare variables based off a number pulled from an input file. I tried using arrays and didn't get far.

```
amountOfQuads = header_line.split(',')[1]
print amountOfQuads
quad = []
print 'test'
for i in range(1,amountOfQuads):
    quad[i] = vtk.vtkQuad()
```

This gives a "range() integer end argument expected, got str" error.

For example, if there's 3, I could just do:

```
quad1 = vtk.vtkQuad()
quad2 = vtk.vtkQuad()
quad3 = vtk.vtkQuad()
```

This would work very well for just 3 squares, but not so much for larger amounts.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Edit: Forgot, this bit of code also gives a "range() integer end argument expected, got str." error

Comment: what's the problem with the list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`amountOfQuads` is a string, but `range` needs an integer.  Also, rather than setting indexes on the list, `append` to the list.

```
amountOfQuads = int(amountOfQuads)
quad = []
for i in range(amountOfQuads):
    quad.append(vtk.vtkQuad())
```

You can just replace this with a comprehension.

```
quad = [vtk.vtkQuad() for _ in range(int(header_line.split(',')[1]))]
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to `append` them to the `list`

```
amountOfQuads = int(header_line.split(',')[1])
print amountOfQuads
quad = []
print 'test'
for i in range(amountOfQuads):
        quad.append(vtk.vtkQuad())
```

Or using list comprehension

```
quad = [vtk.vtkQuad() for _ in range(amountOfQuads)]
```

Comment: I assume the downvotes are because while you've identified the use of `.append` - you've left the error coming from `range` the same as the OP

Comment: Which was not in the question....and not even mentioned in comments when I wrote this.  Answer has been updated

Comment: The OP added a comment instead of an edit 13 mins ago saying: *Edit: Forgot, this bit of code also gives a "range() integer end argument expected, got str." error*